# Insert com Inner Join e várias condições na cláusula where

Tags: android, sqlite

Qual é a melhor forma de fazer um `SELECT` com `INNER JOIN` e com várias condições usando o SQLite Android?

Eu pensei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder _QB = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

_QB.setTables("TABELA_1 INNER JOIN TABELA_2
               ON TABELA_1.ID =TABELA_2.TABELA_1_ID");

String[] columns = new String[]
{
   " SUM (column1) as column1",
   " SUM (column2) as column2"
};

String groupBy = "column1";

String selection = "column1=example1 AND column2=example2";

String orderBy = " column2 ASC ";

SQLiteDatabase db = beginTransactiongin();

Cursor cursor = _QB.query(SQLiteDatabase, columns, selection, null,groupBy, null,orderBy);
```

Comment: Procure ser mais descritivo no seu problema, principalmente no título. Isto ajuda você conseguir um resultado melhor e mais facilmente. Veja também: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-t%C3%ADtulo

Comment: já fiz a alteração acho que agora esta perceptível